# What exerts torque on a pulsar?

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, torque, magnetic-moment, pulsars

I'm modeling a pulsar as a rotating compact body with frequency $\omega(t)$, and magnetic dipole moment misaligned from the axis of rotation by angle $\chi$. It's straightforward to calculate the radiative power leaving the system in the far-field limit: $P\propto \omega^4\sin^2\chi$ (under the assumption that the spin-down rate is slow, $\dot{\omega}\ll\omega^2$).

By energy conservation, we can express the torque on the pulsar: $\tau\propto -\omega^3\sin^2\chi$. My question is, through what mechanism is torque applied to the pulsar? Is the accelerating dipole moment "self-interacting" through the field it generates?

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I understand this is not a realistic model for a pulsar. This is a toy model I'm using to frame my question. The radiation carries away energy and angular momentum, so the pulsar must spin-down - that is clear to me.

What I do not understand is the $\textbf{torque}$. We have a compact massive body losing angular momentum. So there exists a non-zero torque on the pulsar. What object $\textit{exerts}$ this torque?

Comment: Note that pulsars are not well-approximated as magnetic dipoles radiating because they rotate. Otherwise we would receive a radio-wave plane wave on earth from every pulsar with the radio-wave frequency being that pulsar's rotation rate. Rather we receive pulses only from pusars who are aligned with earth at some point in their rotation. The time between pulses is the rotation rate. I mean this is absolutely a great exercise to go through, but it's not going to be accurate.

Comment: @AXensen I am confused: pulsars generate EM waves with a frequency equal to their rotation rate, but too weak to be detectable. The pulse profile (lasting one rotation period) is detected at much higher radio frequencies, frequencies that have nothing to do with rotation. The pulse profile and spectrum depend on the still debated radio emission mechanism that is responsible for the radio beam, probably taking place near the polar caps. It seems to me that the dipole model may not be good for the magnetospheric field... but for other reasons, not because of the existence of beamed radiation.

Comment: @Quillo I don't think you're confused at all. Everything you said was correct. My main point was that (1) the signals we get from pulsars are not at all modelled by rotating dipole radiation, in case that wasn't clear to the author (2) these radio beams are the primary way that pulsars lose energy, and the primary reason their rotation decays over time, not rotating dipole radiation. The question seems to imply you can calculate the spin-down rate of pulsars using the rotating dipole model.

Comment: @AXensen thank you for the clarification, it makes perfect sense. Indeed there are known deviations from the dipolar-spin-down model and most of the detected braking indexes deviate significantly from the canonical "dipole" value of 3, even though in many cases this model for spin-down is reasonable. For the interested reader, the robustness and limits of the model are discussed here (and probably many other papers, but this is one of the most famous): [Time-dependent force-free pulsar magnetospheres: axisymmetric and oblique rotators](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0603147).

Comment: Dear Aiden,  is this answer of any help? [How can a pulsar slow down?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/705799/226902)

Comment: @Quillo Thank you for the response, but that is not the answer I'm looking for. I've updated my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: A dipole may not be a good model of a pulsar, but the torque that slows a rotating dipole can be understood from two things: (1) changes in the magnetic field (due to rotation) propagate at a finite speed, and (2) a magnetic field exerts a torque on a misaligned dipole. If we think of each part of the object as a little dipole, it experiences a torque due to the delayed (hence misaligned) magnetic field from the other moving parts. Are you looking for that type of toy-model answer, or do you want something closer to how a real pulsar presumably works?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly That’s exactly the toy-model answer I’m looking for. Can you provide more details in an answer?

Comment: I'm not in a place to write a new answer, but a while ago I posted an answer to this question: [Would a rotating magnet emit photons? If so, what causes the torque that gradually slows the rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158557) That answer uses a rotating-and-radiating dipole model in which the total angular momentum is conserved, and it uses that model to check the intuition. Maybe that analysis could be boiled down to a simpler essence, which might also have the virtue of being more general. I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

As you state, the dipole will radiate EM radiation with power $P \propto \omega^{4} \sin ^{2} \chi$, with $P > 0$ if $\chi \neq 0$.

But as the radiated EM waves carry momentum $ p \propto E \times B$, so they also carry angular momentum $L = r \times p$, where $r$ is the distance from the axis of rotation ($E, B$ being the electric and magnetic fields). The rate of angular momentum loss can be written as (see [Appendix B](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1969ApJ...157.1395O&defaultprint=YES&page_ind=0&filetype=.pdf) here)
$$ \dot{L}=\dot{\mathcal{E}} / \omega$$
where $\dot{\mathcal{E}}$ is the energy loss rate.

**Adddition** :
To clarify my earlier sloppy remark: [As I read](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.05584.pdf), the source of the magnetic field of a neutron star is typically associated with its crust as the core region is assumed to become a Type-I superconductor, which expells the magnetic field owing to the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect).

In this crust region, it is typically the electrons that can move relatively freely (e.g., due to [circulation currents](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1925Obs....48...73E&defaultprint=YES&page_ind=0&filetype=.pdf) owing to [von Zeipel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Zeipel_theorem), but there may be more reasons).

These currents will produce a magnetic field, and if the entire system starts to rotate, then this results in a time-varying magnetic field, which results in EM radiation.

**What causes the torque?**
If the OP agrees that the radiation takes away angular momentum at the rate $ \dot{L}=\dot{\mathcal{E}} / \omega$, then the change in mass of the neutron star is $\delta M = \delta \mathcal{E} /c^2$ and change in angular momentum is $\delta L = \delta \mathcal{M}c^2 /\omega$. This implies a change in specific angular momentum $\ell 
 = c^2 /\omega$.

However, if we assume solid body rotation, then the maximum specific angular momentum of the matter in the star can be $\ell = I\omega / M \approx R^2\omega$, $I, M, R$ being the moment of inertia, mass and radius of the star.

*As $c^2/\omega \gg R^2 \omega$, so the radiation takes away much more specific angular momentum than is carried by any part of the star. As such, the entire configuration has to slow down.*

If the OP is after a mechanism using which the star slows down during the emission of radiation, then I think one would need to instead focus on the light-matter interaction problem and deal with it quantum mechanically. But qualitatively, *the neutron star is slowing down due to redistribution of angular momentum where the radiation takes away a relatively large chunk with it.*

Comment: I upvoted because the most important part of the answer looks correct to me. However, I find the statement "it would be helpful to think of the rotating star as rotating (accelerating) charges going in a circular motion" wrong. The star is macroscopically neutral. You just need a time-varying field to radiate (and you have it, the rotating B-field). In fact, a rotating but non-magnetised neutron star would not spin down (unless you consider other causes for the spin down, like GW emission).

Comment: @S.G This is not the answer I'm looking for. I've updated my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @Quillo Thank you for the catch. I have made some additions to my reply now.

Comment: @Aiden I think I still do not answer your question, but I have updated my answer anyway.

Comment: @S.G Thanks for updating! The system in the OP is classical, so I would think there's a classical explanation - no need for QM. When deriving the torque, we only need to assume the "pulsar" is a massive compact rotating body. I'm looking for an explanation of the interaction using identical assumptions.